# Using Phaser for Babylonjs Dynamic Texture

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework, babylonjs

I'm creating a 3d game using Babylon.js and saw that using Dynamic Texture (https://doc.babylonjs.com/how_to/dynamictexture) you can use canvas elements for the texture: `var ctx = myDynamicTexture.getContext();`. Is there some way to project a PhaserJS canvas onto a texture of a 3D element in Babylon.js? I know it can be done in three.js, but I like Babylon.js better and don'
t want to switch.

Answer (score 0):

The second variable of the DynamicTexture constructor can be an already-existing canvas with 2d context (https://doc.babylonjs.com/how_to/dynamictexture#creating-and-applying-a-dynamic-texture). It will use the canvas's width and height to define the texture's size:

```js
const phaserCanvas = getMyPhaserCanvas();
const dt = new DynamicTexture('phaser canvas', phaserCanvas, babylonScene);
```